# How to send touches in modal view controller to parent view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboardsegue, uicontainerview

I have a base view controller VC1 and another view controller VC2 that is modally presented over full screen (over VC1)

VC2 is semi transparent and I would like to forward all touch events from VC2 to VC1 when the user taps or scrolls.  (VC1 has a few buttons and a scrollview)

Should I use some kind of custom container?  How can I present VC2 to cover the screen and yet forward all touches to VC1?  Is modal the right answer?

I have tried storing a reference to VC1 as a variable in VC2 and passing events to VC1 via touchesbegan but that has not worked.

Thank you.

Comment: what do you want?  if scrollview in vc2 scrolling, scrollview in vc1 scroll? OR vc1 just catch scroll event of scrollview in vc2

Comment: The buttons and scrollview are all in VC1.  I want any touch/press on VC2 to go straight to VC1 and bypass VC2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass event to different views, then you should use subView instead of VC2.

Make new UIView *secondView and add as subView of VC1.

```
[self.view addSubView:secondView];
```

Not put the following method in your VC1.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   UIView *hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

   // check your condition here, if button is pressed on secondView and you want to pass event on mainview the simply return mainView. This event will be passed to mainView.

   if ([secondView.button isEqual:hitView])
   {

      return self.view;
   }
   else
   {
      return nil;
   }

   return hitView;
 }
```

Comment: Agree with this approach 100%, but I've already made a VC with outlets/storyboard and don't want to remake everything into a seperate uiview.  Is there a way to present the viewcontroller as a subview?

Comment: Use this: https://github.com/mohshin-shah/MSAlertView
Copy your VC's design from storyboard and create new xib and paste.
hope you didn't need to create any outlet again.
This will present your xib as as a subview of Viewcontroller's view.